# How to create a zip file of a specific directory in maven?

Tags: java, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRpy1.png)Can any one help me with this. Using maven , I need to create  zip file with of a directory , which is inside the project.

Any example will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven assembly plugin can create a zip file of anything you want. The documentation is pretty good, you can see an example [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html).

The gist of it is adding an xml file that describes how files are to be assembled, and then reference that from pom.xml. Here's an example of the assembly descriptor (taken from the website):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>README.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>LICENSE.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>NOTICE.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

And then in `pom.xml` you'd reference this file like so (assuming the file is called `distribution.xml` under the `assembly` directory):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   [...]
</project>
```

There's a bunch more options to help you filter out files or include/exclude directories and so on. All in the docs.

Comment: <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0</version>
 <configuration>
  <descriptors>
  <descriptor>\src\main\assembly\bin.xml</descriptor>
  </descriptors>
  </configuration>
 <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>create-zipfile</id>
  <phase>install</phase>
   <goals>
   <goal>single</goal>
  </goals>
  </execution>
  </executions>
 </plugin>

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you add that to a snippet in your original post.

Comment: i added snipped in original post

Comment: Your bin.xml is apparently missning an `<id/>` tag. See the error message at the bottom of the image you posted.

Comment: I never thought that it was going in bin.xml, i was thiking in parent pom it was complaining. Thanks for catching. this Issue  is  resolved.Thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted, so avoid other people trying to answer this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087114/how-can-we-zip-two-separate-directories-in-seperate-zip-files-using-assembly-pli have posted another question can you help? related one.

Comment: The provided link is now outdated (13 jun 2022), @Kraylog can you include a digest of the plugin usage in your answer ?

Comment: @Zilog80 there ya go.