# How can we zip two separate directories in seperate zip files, using assembly plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have tried below with same assembly descriptor with two executions in `pom.xml`.

The problem is both zip files are mixing since they are calling one after other the same file.

Is there any way we can achieve this without going for two different assembly descriptor files?

[image: File One]
[image: File Two]

Comment: Added formatting to some filenames/code. Added pictures to question (not just links to them) to make question self-sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create two different zip files from two different directories, you'll need two different assembly descriptors.
Each descriptor describes which files go into the end result.

Comment: Okay, ty for response. But when we have to 2 files seperately. we need two executions right? Because i want to name with seperate zip files

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Thankyou for clarification. I am marking this as success.

Comment: i have put another post can u help? i dont know to communicate with you.......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108814/context-root-path-not-working-in-jboss-7-ear